# Can you pass the result of a function as parameter to stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SqlServer 2005, is it possible to do something like this where SomeFunction returns a value. Eg 1234

```
EXEC [dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure] @SomeParameter = SomeFunction()
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it, it did not work, thus I asked the question if it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to declare a variable first to hold the result of the function.  You can then pass the variable to the stored procedure

```
Declare @FunctionResult int

Select @FunctionResult = dbo.YourFunction()

Exec dbo.YourStoredProcedure @FunctionResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems I don't have enough reputation to comment on the accepted answer.

Here's a more concise syntax where the declaration and the assignation of the variable is done in one line:

```sql
Declare @FunctionResult int = dbo.YourFunction()

Exec dbo.YourStoredProcedure @FunctionResult
```

Comment: this does not bring any new and really helpful information.